# What do "?" and ":" mean in this PHP line of code?

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert this PHP function to Objective-C. I can just barely read PHP to figure out what the code does. Came across this line and stopped:

```
$nr = (strlen($nr)-3>0)?substr($nr, 0, strlen($nr)-3):"";
```

What do the `?` and `:` do here? I read the documentation to see what `strlen` and `substr` do but haven't been able to figure out how this comes together and what the new value of `$nr` is.

Comment: The code is not Python, but `?:` is the ternary operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: I think everyone's missing the point, focusing on the Python vs PHP rather than the actual question about the ternary operator.

Comment: Ok. It's PHP, sorry about that.

Comment: @FeifanZ The actual question is a clear duplicate. Next time, instead of hunting reputation answering it with a cheap answer, search for the duplicate and vote to close.

Comment: Sorry about this. It was my mistake, as I got PHP confused with Python. I accepted an answer and gave the runners up votes. Thank you so much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?:` is a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). The expression `x ? y : z` means `if x then y else z`. In this case, it would translate to something like

```
if strlen($nr) - 3 > 0:
    $nr = substr($nr, 0, strlen($nr) - 3)
else:
    $nr = ''
```

Comment: It's a ternary operator in some languages, but in python it's just invalid syntax.

Comment: True... sorry about this... it's PHP. I'm about as good at PHP as I am at Python. Edited the title and tag.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the correct one. Something along the lines of: $var = (condition) ? if_true : if_false

Comment: ?: is the ternary operator. If condition is true, $var will be assigned the value if_true; otherwise it will be assigned the value if_false. I found this on another thread... so another 2 min and I will be able to accept the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not Python, but if you were to break it into psuedo-Python syntax it would be

```
if strlen($nr) - 3 > 0:
     $nr = substr($nr, 0, strlen($nr)-3)
else:
     $nr = ""
```

In various languages, the `?` operator is a ternary operator. This syntax does not exist in Python. The above is how you would write such a statement, though you'd have to correct the syntax in each of the if blocks, as well as the if condition.

Comment: If this isn't Python then what is it?

Comment: Read the comments on your post ;)

Comment: You're right... seems to be PHP, I edited the tag and title. My PHP is as good as my Python :D Questions still stands!

Answer (score 1):

it will translate to

```
if (strlen($nr)-3>0) then value of $nr is substr($nr, 0, strlen($nr)-3) 
else it is ""
```

And i dont think the code is in python it looks like php or perl.